# Vue.js: Textarea inside v-for loop is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

v-model value inside v-for loop is not unique.

This is my template:

```
   <template>
      <div
        id="FAQ"
        v-for="(question, index) in questions.slice().reverse()" 
        :key="index"
        class="m-2 col-7"
      >
          <div v-if="getloggedUser.role == 'tutor'">
            <div id="divQuestion">
              <p class="m-5">{{ question.text }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="divAnswer" class="mt-2">
              <p class="m-2">{{ question.answer }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div v-else>
            <div id="divQuestion">
              <p class="m-5">{{ question.text }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="divAnswer" class="mt-2">
              <p class="m-2">{{ question.answer }}</p>
            </div>
            <div v-if="question.answer == null" id="divPsycAnswer">
              <textarea cols="60" rows="3" style="border-radius:12px" v-model="answer.text"></textarea>
              <button id="btnSend" @click="publishAnswer(question.id)">Responder</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div> 
   </template>
```

This is the script (data):

```
  data() {
    return {
      // arrayFAQ: [],
      form: {
        text: ""
      },
      answer: {
        text: ''
      },
      questions: [],
      message: "",
      loading: false,
      id: null
    }
  },
```

This way, everytime I write in one textarea, I write for all the others. I have tried adding [index] in the v-model but there's this error: **"TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in "**

Answer (score 2):

Try this as your v-model

```
<textarea v-model="answers[`text${index}`]"></textarea>
```

The answer object could be an empty object.
It will give you text0, text1, text2, as answer's properties.
You can add anything instead of index, like your question's id for easy access and knowing which text is from which question.

Comment: Should I change the name of the object to "answers" in the data just like it is in v-model?

Comment: Yes you sholud, or you could just make it "answer".